# Show another image onmouseover in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2012, onmouseover

I am having a problem with my javascript in Visual Studio. What I want to do is when i hover over the region of the country, like on this site www.pazar3.mk, a new image from that region should appear (which is transparent) with new color. I am going to post the code that I have. It doesn't return errors, but it doesn't work either. It just takes me to another .aspx site when I click on the region and it doesn't show the other image with the new color. Here's the code that I have, so please, can you tell me what I'm missing or should I change something with my code?

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"      Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 530px;
        height: 380px;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 10px;
        top: 399px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        width: 530px;
        height: 380px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function newImage(arg) {
        if (document.images) {
            rslt = new Image();
            rslt.src = arg;
            return rslt;
        }
    }

    function changeImages() {
        if (document.images && (preloadFlag == true)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < changeImages.arguments.length; i += 2) {
                document[changeImages.arguments[i]].src = changeImages.arguments[i + 1];
            }
        }
    }

    var preloadFlag = false;
    function preloadImages() {
        if (document.images) {
            img1 = newImage("Sliki/1.gif");
            img2 = newImage("Sliki/2.gif");
            img12 = newImage("Sliki/12.gif");
            img23 = newImage("Sliki/23.gif");

            preloadFlag = true;
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="preloadImages();" >
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div  style="height: 386px; width: 906px">  
    <img  src="Sliki/map (1).jpg" width="530" height="380"  id="map"
                usemap="#m_map" alt="" /><map name="m_map" id="m_map">
                    <area shape="poly" coords="167,335,168,321,166,318,161,313,156,308,148,308,146,304,143,302,137,301,136,293,133,283,130,277,127,273,127,270,129,266,133,261,133,253,132,248,128,242,124,240,121,240,118,243,114,248,108,254,100,258,94,261,92,261,91,268,87,274,83,279,81,281,81,286,81,291,81,295,75,298,69,304,67,308,66,316,69,318,79,319,86,319,88,321,91,324,94,326,100,325,102,322,103,317,100,315,95,314,88,312,85,308,87,303,90,300,94,297,98,294,104,293,109,293,113,295,119,303,124,311,127,318,130,327,131,335,132,338,135,336,140,332,144,331,148,331,151,333,155,336,162,336,167,335"
                        href="Default2.aspx" title="Resen" alt="Resen" onmouseover="changeImages('map', 'Sliki/23.gif'); return true;"
                        onmouseout="changeImages('map', 'Sliki/map(1).jpg'); return true;" onmousedown="changeImages('map', 'Sliki/23.gif'); return true;"
                        onmouseup="changeImages('map', 'Sliki/23.gif'); return true;" />
                    </map>    
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Any live demo available?

Comment: You know you can do this very easily in CSS alone without the JS correct? Just change the background img using CSS. Is all you are trying to do is change the images on hover?